# CentOS 6 WiFi using NetworkManager and Without GUI tools

Tags: wifi, centos6, wpa, networkmanager, wpa2

I am using **CentOS 6**, trying desperately to get Wifi working via a `ifcfg-wlan0` file and fudging with `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I do not have an X server, so I do not want to use the GUI tools.

How can I configure NetworkManager to have **WPA2-PSK** WiFi on wlan0 with an ESSID of `inet_bridge`. Ethernet works fine, so I know that my setup isn't completely messed up. Must be done at the command line or with vim.

My **wpa_supplicant.conf**:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel

network={
    ssid="inet_bridge"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=WPA RSN
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    psk="thisIsMyAsciiPassword"
}
```

My **ifcfg-wlan0**:

```
DEVICE=wlan0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.0.253
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS1=192.168.0.99
HWADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
TYPE=Wireless
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that `wpa_supplicant` was not being started with correct command line arguments. So it was not authenticating with the WPA2 Encrypted Access point because WPA2 was disabled in the supplicant.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't know how to do this with `NetworkManager`. However, I would like to point you out to my favorite network client - `Wicd`. Install it, there is CentOS 6 RPM available. Then start its `wicd-ncurses` interface and you can set it up once and forget about it. When you are done, disable your `NetworkManager` service and enable the wicd one. No need to touch the wpa_supplicant service. Wicd keeps its configuration files under `/etc/wicd` directory and your password will be stored in clear text in file called `wireless-settings.conf`. However, this file is 0600, owned by root.

Comment: This seriously should be the official "correct" answer...

Comment: Can you confirm it is still maintained? Their [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/wicd/+series) suggests no major updates since April 2012.

Comment: @MDMoore313 - no, I can't. The page you listed has it all. At the bottom of the list there are some newer packages, still 1.7.x though.